# how to remove item from jtoolbar

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

private JButton btnTask = new JButton();
...
TaoGlobal.taskbar.add(btnTask);

How to remove btnTask from JToolBar?

Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i tried remove, but forgotten for
>   repaint

Well the general code should be:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The revalidate() is important because it tells the panel to layout the components. Your code may work if your are removing the last component, but I doubt is will work when you remove the first component.

Answer (score 2):

`JToolBar` is a `Container`, and hence removal can be achieved via [`toolbar.remove(btnTask)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove%28java.awt.Component%29).

If you look at that javadoc you'll see other useful methods, like `remove(index)` and `removeAll()`.

Comment: thanx, i tried remove, but forgotten for repaint:

      TaoGlobal.taskbar.remove(btnTask);
      TaoGlobal.taskbar.repaint();

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would be useful for you:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html
and
http://java.sun.com/j2se/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html

The last link shows you all the methods that you can use.